# What Weld CDI can @Inject without declaring a @Produces in JSF 2.1+ application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, dependency-injection, cdi, weld

What Weld CDI can @Inject without declaring a @Produces in JSF 2.1+ application?

As I understand, it can inject FacesContext in properly set up web application.

Can it inject:

- HttpSession?
- context-param from web.xml (ala ServletContext.getInitParameter(xxx))
- env-ref from web.xml

Comment: No, none of these are injectable with CDI Natively.  You'll need to use an extension of some kind

Comment: When John says "extension" the easiest way to do this would be with a producer from things such as a Servlet Filter or ServletListener (Listeners are a bit easier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I tested (and also according to the [Weld Spec 1.1](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1/cdi-spec.html#additional_builtin_beans)) you can inject `javax.security.Principal` and `javax.transaction.UserTransaction` in Java EE environment. This works for me fine on JBoss AS 7.2 with CDI version `1.1-PRD`.

And for the Servlet container, it is it's responsibility to make these objects injectable for your application

- `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`
- `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession`
- `javax.servlet.ServletContext`

However, not every container can really support this (and also I didn't test this but I suppose it should work - I've already seen this code somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my own answer to this question.

There is incubating **Apache** project [**DeltaSpike**](http://deltaspike.apache.org).

> DeltaSpike consist of a number of portable CDI extensions that provide useful features for Java application developers.

According to the documentation, the Servlet module allows injection of ServletContext, HttpSession and Principal objects.

However, I have taken a different path and implemented context parameter injection myself, using @Producer method with InjectionPoint argument. It is rather simple really.

First create a annotation for parameter which will hold context-param name attribute.

```java
@Qualifier
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface WebContextParameter {
    @Nonbinding String value() default "";
}
```

Annotation attribute name() must be declared as `@Nonbinding` so CDI will not use it as part of qualifying process.

Second, create producer bean with @Produce method

```java
public class WebContextParameterProducer {
    @Inject
    private ServletContext context;

    @Produces
    @WebContextParameter()
    public String createWebContextParameter(InjectionPoint ip) {
        WebContextParameter annotation = null;
        for (Iterator<Annotation> it = ip.getQualifiers().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Annotation n = it.next();
            if (n.annotationType().equals(WebContextParameter.class)) {
                annotation = (WebContextParameter) n;
                break;
            }
        }       

        return context.getInitParameter(annotation.value());
    }
}
```

After that, use anywhere in your code:

```
@Inject
@WebContextParameter("my.config.option")
String myConfigOption = "default-value";
```

Please note, however, the "default-value" will be used only in non CDI environment. In CDI, `myConfigOption` will be set to `null` if no value will be found in web.xml. This example can be expanded adding additional `defaultValue()` attribute to annotation to alleviate this.

So basically, ServletContext is already @Inject-able, so the rest of the stuff from it is injectable too.